# Self referencing of a schema not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

Following is my Schema -

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Create Schema
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    created_by: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    created_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

// compile Schema into a model
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

// Make this instance available when require()d
module.exports = User;
```

Following is the error I am getting -

```
/trialcoder/project/server/models/user.js:26
    created_by: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
                        ^
ReferenceError: Schema is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/trialcoder/project/server/models/user.js:26:25)
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong as currently I am following the second approach reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24483532/1594368)

FYI - I deleted some fields so line number may not be the same here.

Comment: As I said in your previous question. Many people prefer to import "Schema" as it's own `variable` definition for this reason. Either do that or code long as "mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId"

Comment: @NeilLunn man u awesome....how is ur mongodb so strong ? :) paste it as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: No need. It's just coming to terms with using node in general and how things are defined. I'd be surprised if there was not a duplicate question somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Schema doesn't exist, you need to use: `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` to access the object reference, or create a variable with that name and store `moongoseSchema` in it.:

```
var moongose,
    Schema = `mongoose.Schema`;
```